# Laptop Energy Saving When Downloading

Tags: sleep, download, energy-saving

I have to download some **VERY** large files from Microsoft overnight for a few days as I am on a relative low download speed in the UK countryside.

However, I am concerned about the energy consumption over this period. I have tried to put my laptop in sleep mode while downloading, but it does not seem to work. The download just shuts off and pauses.

I have tried to shut off the display to nothing with the blue-function key then the left and right arrows. That seems to work for about an hour, but if I leave it for more than an hour like that then I have to reset the machine, because I cannot get back into it otherwise. If I leave it at 1 notch above complete blackness, then that seems to work ok. However, 1 notch above zero still seems to produce a lot of light; something I would not like to have in my bedroom while I tried to sleep.

Can I download in sleep mode in some way?

What can I do so my computer is on minimal energy output during these periods? (The laptop will be doing nothing except downloading.)

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to blank your screen when you are not working with
the computer, choose the "Blank" screen-saver.

This is done at *Start > Change screen saver*.
You can test it using the Preview button.

Comment: This is useful. Thanks. I will wait to see if there are any more suggestions before marking this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Also try Nirsoft (nirsoft.net) Monitor OFF  (batch file and monitor is completely black.

Nirsoft app is nircmd.exe

C:\Applications and Technical\NirCommand

Then make a batch file:

"c:\applications and technical\nircommand\nircmd" monitor off

This is a nice method because you can turn the monitor OFF on demand when you are finished your work.